# Watchdog timeout killing ActivityManager

Tags: android

We are seeing random reboots while capturing the bugreport.
From traces,Binder is holding a lock and performing some file operations,while activity manager waits to acquire the same lock on release.
But for some reason Binder fails to complete the operation with in stipulated time of 60 secs(watchdog timeout period) after which watchdog would kick in and kill the activity manager resulting in a reboot.
Not sure why the file operations are failing.
Any idea??

```
****Logcat****
28429 28736 W Watchdog: *** WATCHDOG KILLING SYSTEM PROCESS: Blocked in monitor com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService on foreground thread (android.fg), Blocked in handler on ActivityManager (ActivityManager)
28429 28736 W Watchdog: foreground thread stack trace:
28429 28736 W Watchdog: at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.monitor(ActivityManagerService.java :18792)
28429 28736 W Watchdog:     at com.android.server.Watchdog$HandlerChecker.run(Watchdog.java:173)
28429 28736 W Watchdog:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
28429 28736 W Watchdog:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
28429 28736 W Watchdog:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
28429 28736 W Watchdog:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
28429 28736 W Watchdog:     at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
28429 28736 W Watchdog: ActivityManager stack trace:
28429 28736 W Watchdog:     at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService.noteProcessState(BatteryStatsService.java:159)
28429 28736 W Watchdog:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.setProcessTrackerStateLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:18077)
28429 28736 W Watchdog:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.updateOomAdjLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:18503)
28429 28736 W Watchdog:     at com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue.processCurBroadcastLocked(BroadcastQueue.java:234)
28429 28736 W Watchdog:     at com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue.processNextBroadcast(BroadcastQueue.java:893)
28429 28736 W Watchdog:     at com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue$BroadcastHandler.handleMessage(BroadcastQueue.java:149)
28429 28736 W Watchdog:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
28429 28736 W Watchdog:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
28429 28736 W Watchdog:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
28429 28736 W Watchdog:     at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
28429 28736 W Watchdog: *** GOODBYE!

****Traces****
"ActivityManager" prio=5 tid=14 Blocked
 | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12d49d60 self=0xb4835000
 | sysTid=28447 nice=-2 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb48ab400
 | state=S schedstat=( 122941894282 79694427844 199108 ) utm=7937 stm=4357 core=0 HZ=100
 | stack=0xa4dd4000-0xa4dd6000 stackSize=1036KB
 | held mutexes=
 at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService.noteProcessState(BatteryStatsService.java:159)
 - waiting to lock <0x1630e0b8> (a com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl) held by thread 63
 at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.setProcessTrackerStateLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:18077)
 at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.updateOomAdjLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:18503)
 at com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue.processCurBroadcastLocked(BroadcastQueue.java:234)
 at com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue.processNextBroadcast(BroadcastQueue.java:893)
 - locked <0x1d97ee91> (a com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService)
 at com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue$BroadcastHandler.handleMessage(BroadcastQueue.java:149)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
 at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
 at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)

"Binder_7" prio=5 tid=63 Native`enter code here`
 | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x13057400 self=0xa3867000
 | sysTid=28848 nice=-20 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb0052280
 | state=S schedstat=( 99308593770 7649047774 35537 ) utm=9244 stm=686 core=1 HZ=100
 | stack=0xa06db000-0xa06dd000 stackSize=1012KB
 | held mutexes=
 kernel: (couldn't read /proc/self/task/28848/stack)
 native: #00 pc 000133c4  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+28)
 native: #01 pc 000a983f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable4WaitEPNS_6ThreadE+82)
 native: #02 pc 001b187f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI12NewStringUTFEP7_JNIEnvPKc+738)
 native: #03 pc 00018849  /system/lib/libjavacore.so (???)
 native: #04 pc 0001e66d  /system/lib/libjavacore.so (???)
 native: #05 pc 0001e743  /system/lib/libjavacore.so (???)
 native: #06 pc 00020b4f  /system/lib/libjavacore.so (???)
 native: #07 pc 0027a9a3  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat (Java_libcore_io_Posix_writeBytes__Ljava_io_FileDescriptor_2Ljava_lang_Object_2II+142)
 at libcore.io.Posix.writeBytes(Native method)
 at libcore.io.Posix.write(Posix.java:258)
 at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.write(BlockGuardOs.java:313)
 at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:497)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:186)
 at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.flushBytesLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:334)
 at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.flushLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:355)
 at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.appendLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:303)
 at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.print(FastPrintWriter.java:466)
 - locked <@addr=0x130f2630> (a com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter$DummyWriter)
 at android.os.BatteryStats.printBitDescriptions(BatteryStats.java:3427)
 at android.os.BatteryStats$HistoryPrinter.printNextItem(BatteryStats.java:3653)
 at android.os.BatteryStats.dumpHistoryLocked(BatteryStats.java:3907)
 at android.os.BatteryStats.dumpCheckinLocked(BatteryStats.java:4110)
 at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService.dump(BatteryStatsService.java:933)
 - locked <0x1630e0b8> (a com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl)
 at android.os.Binder.dump(Binder.java:319)
 at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:285)
 at com.android.internal.app.IBatteryStats$Stub.onTransact(IBatteryStats.java:832)
 at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it is a very old post, i stumbled upon a similar problem where the Activity Manager was getting killed by Watchdog. However, in my case the problem turned out to be of low system memory where the lowmemorykiller was getting invoked. As full dumpstate is not available, i can just provide some suggestions as below:

If you were able to solve the problem, please do post your view.

If it is expected that the bugreport is huge or there is some network operation involved, we can try to increase the "extra time" the watchdog provides to a blocked thread to finish.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/7e361d2/services/java/com/android/server/Watchdog.java

```
@Override
public void run() {
```

...

```
// Give some extra time to make sure the stack traces get written.
        // The system's been hanging for a minute, another second or two won't hurt much.
        SystemClock.sleep(2000);
```

Lastly, to debug the root cause, if we attach the debugger, the watchdog won't kill the ActivityManager.

```
// Only kill the process if the debugger is not attached.
        if (Debug.isDebuggerConnected()) {
            Slog.w(TAG, "Debugger connected: Watchdog is *not* killing the system process");
        }
```